# When using Xamarin MessageCenter should I unsubscribe before or after base.OnDisappearing();

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I call a method to do unsubscribe of messages in my OnDisappearing().

Should I do this after the base.OnDisappearing()

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
   base.OnDisappearing();
   Unsubscribe();
}
```

or before the base.OnDisappearing()

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
   Unsubscribe();
   base.OnDisappearing();
}

private void Unsubscribe()
{
   MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<SettingsPageViewModel>(this, "OpenATIPage");
   MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<SettingsPageViewModel>(this, "OpenCFSPage");
   MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<SettingsPageViewModel>(this, "OpenCVMPage");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb for me, not sure how other developers do it, this is the pattern I use for `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing`.

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    // User code for events and such
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    // User code for events and such

    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

I like having everything cleaned up before XF decides to clean up some resources from the `OnDisappearing` event. Also, I like to call XF `OnAppearing` before I do work, just so they can get everything they need initialized first.